# Python x-labels evenly spreaded

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to get my labels turned up correctly.
I want it to show 10 values on the list, but I have no idea how.
The usual way to show it doesn't work and when there are a lot of values, it is hard to read, see the picture.[image]

Here you see that it is impossible to read the data.
Do you have an idea to make it work properly?

I have tried autoDateLocator, but that didn't work. The axis values were wrong.
I also tried to do that manually, but the same result happened.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you saying that you only want to see 10 ticks? (labels in x axis)

Comment: yes, I want to see only 10 ticks, to keep the usability for displaying the sequence. Checking what happened over christmas and other holidays while still being able to keep the information.

It did automaticly choose the ticks when I didn't want to display the day of the week, but as some data varies a lot depending on the day of the week, I would like to keep that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have kinda 'solved this issue'. I asked around and didn't really find an answer that suited my needs, as every tick always gets shown.
However, when I keep the xtick_labels in the datetime-format, it gets sorted out by matplotlib itself, if there are too many values to show. This according to the dataset Armamatita provided

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime

import numpy as np

x = np.array([datetime.datetime(i,1,1) for i in range(1700,2017)])
y = np.random.randint(0,100,len(x))
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x,y)

plt.show()
```

[image]

I when the days I want to see is more than 14, I just let matplotlib pick te xtick_labels. When equal or less than 14, I add it myself using:

`alldays = DayLocator()
weekFormatter = DateFormatter('%a %b %d %Y')`

and this right before returning the fig:

`ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(alldays)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(weekFormatter)`

It isn't the most neat pythonic code, but it does the trick.